# Can we impersonate user and password to display Tableau dashboard in mvc?

Tags: tableau-api

I want to integrate in MVC application and by pass-login screen of tableau. I need to pass custom (single) user credentials.

Comment: Yes, this is possible; I'm doing something similar now. Configure your Tableau instance to require token generation (i.e. to use the JavaScript API to render an iframe). You can then add users at your web-app level and control access to the token generation using your own access control system. Be aware that it is not a trivial project though.

Comment: However, there is no "impersonation" as such - from Tableau's perspective you'd be running under a single AD account.

Comment: Yes thanks it works now

Answer (score 1):

Use [Trusted Authentication](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm) to create a ticket which can then be used to embed the dashboard in your MVC app.